# Alternative to SplitView for Horizontal Menus with dynamic sub menu

Tags: c#, uwp, splitview

Can anybody advise me on what would be the best method to implement the following example?
A splitView would would be perfect but for the fact that you can't change the orientation.

Can anybody suggest an alternative?

The contents of the bottom Dynamic panel will need to change based on the menu item selected, just in case that wasn't clear enough.

Thanks

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you try the Pivot control?

Comment: You can use command bar or app bar alternately create custom user control, command bar or app bar will be the perfect choice which allow you to create similar to your screenshot with borders between buttons

Comment: You can try `MenuControl` as mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/menu) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **Pivot** view, **Menu** (from windows community toolkit) or new **Navigtion View** from **win ui** library
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/pivot

Comment: Thanks. I had discounted Pivot view for a number of aesthetic reasons, but with some workarounds, I've managed to get it how I want it.

Comment: great, please considering accepting the answer if it works for you thanks. @AdamMcMahon